# How can I download file in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, download, codeigniter-2, force-download

I am trying to download file in my codeigniter web application using javascript and codeigniter controller, it shows the file contents in ASCII format but not download the file directly

**view.php**

```
<a href="javascript:prd_download(this)">Download</a>

<img src="<?php echo site_url()."/../images/uploads/".$jobno."/thumb_".$prd_row->filename; ?>" alt="Loading Image..." >

<input type="checkbox" name="img_check" id="img_check" class="img_check" image="<?php echo $prd_row->filename ?>">


<script type="text/javascript">
function prd_download(ele)
{   
    var selected_images = $(".img_check:checked");

    var job_no = $("#product_table").attr("jobno");

    var image_name = new Array();

    for(i = 0; i < selected_images.length; i++)
    {
        image_name[i] = $(selected_images[i]).attr('image');
    }

        $.get('<?php echo site_url('project_controller/file_download') ?>', {file_name : image_name, jobno : job_no});
}
</script>
```

**controller.php**

```
function file_download()
    {
        $url_para = $_GET['file_name'];
        $job_no = $_GET['jobno'];
        $this->load->helper('download');
        $data = file_get_contents(site_url().'/../images/uploads/'.$job_no."/".$url_para[0]);
        $name = 'myphoto.jpg';

        force_download($name, $data);
}
```

I had tried by changing path also, but its not working...

Comment: `site_url().'/../images/uploads/` seems invalid. Try starting with `/images/uploads/..`

Comment: check if any console errors ?

Comment: Try to use 'base_url()' instead of `site_url()`

Comment: @Bora when I use site_url().'/../images/uploads/  and print this in a variable the variable value is perfect which shows me the file which am going to download.

Comment: @AzamAlvi I have tried, but not working... :(

Comment: @Arunu There is no console error

Comment: Yes, you could going bellow link its perfect solution. [Click Me](http://www.innovativephp.com/image-downloading-issue-codeigniter-download-helper)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made changes in my javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function prd_download(ele)
{   
    var selected_images = $(".img_check:checked");

    var job_no = $("#product_table").attr("jobno");

    var image_name = new Array();

    for(i = 0; i < selected_images.length; i++)
    {
        image_name[i] = $(selected_images[i]).attr('image');
    }

        window.location.href = "<?php echo site_url('project_controller/file_download') ?>?file_name="+ image_name +"&jobno="+ job_no;
}
</script>
```

In javascript I called controller directly, cause `$.get` function treat like call back...

Now its working fine...! :) :D